# Ajax/Java errors but can't find issue

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

here is link to the search  page on the site. http://www.datehero.com/member/search.php, I also have done several sites with this platform ( skadate 9 ) and never had this issue. the template design I have used on 3 others without this issue. But I came into this project with the site already set up. I have found almost nothing on the developer tools in FF or Chrome to indicate the problem. some errors i compared with my other working site to see what differences there was.  not really finding anything different between the working one and the one having errors I am at a lost.

I am getting Data Null errors on several forms on the site, including the login, join and search pages. anywhere really where they have to submit a form.

here is the error when running a Search : 
Date Hero informs

```
{exec: new Function("window.location.href = \"http:\\\/\\\/www.datehero.com\\\/member\\\/profile_list.php?sex=2&match_sex%5B0%5D=1&birthdate%5B0%5D=20&birthdate%5B1%5D=103&new_search=1&search_type=main\";\n"), data: null}
```

now when you get the error message on login it still logs them in.. just takes like a 10 sec delay before it changes to the members page.

Found some info that attracta messes up ajax on several platforms but doesn't seems to be on the site.  so i am trying to figure out what could be causing it.  I disabled all of my own personal code recently to test it.  but it was still there.

so hoping someone can help spot the issue on here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember that as a community we want to create answers that are useful in future. That means that a link to your site where you will probably soon have the problem fixed won't help future users. Instead you could describe what happens when you make a request- what does the form html look like? What is the ajax code you are using? What do you find in your browser development tool network logs? What message are you getting from the logging on your server? These should help narrow things down so you can either solve the problem or ask a clear, answerable, question.

Comment: thanks for the welcome and almost useless reply.  i will make the edit to include more data..  for this end.. but the platform is very rarely used and no longer obtainable so not many will be asking this.